MySQL 8 fails to record binary session data in MEDIUMTEXT column
I have a table like this:
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `id` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `access` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `access_idx` (`access`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

In MySQL 5 that worked perfectly well when I stored a small binary object in the session.
In MySQL 8 the stored session data is cut off right where that binary object starts. So when I load the session after writing the session with the binary data, session_start() fails to deserialize the session data and immediately calls session_destroy()
We changed the data column to mediumblob and that fixes the error.
So two questions: What changed between MySQL 5 and 8, and is there a problem with using a BLOB column for session storage?

It seems like use of MEDIUMBLOB would work for storing that binary data correctly.  But you would need to make sure your character sets are correct.  When they upgraded, from 5 to 8 MySQL, seems that they added some stricter requirements for TEXT and thus truncation can happen, which you obviously don't want to happen with a binary stream.

Question is: why did you store binary data in a text column in the first place? @easleyfixed I don't think mysql 5 had utf8mb4 character set and its utf8 implementation was only max 3 bytes long. Upgrade that to 4 byte utf8 and you can run out space.

@shadow I never heard of such a thing before either, but if its possible someone will do it.  But the BLOB fix is the correct way, and the answer is due to text being more strict in the newer version.

@Shadow The binary data was in a cryptographic challenge stored in the session for convenience for comparison in the very next request.

@easleyfixed if you placed that info as an answer I'd accept it

@easleyfixed the other way around - mysql newer implementation of utf8 includes full utf8 range - hence the 4 byte storage requirement. The old one was more restrictive requiring only 3 bytes.

Interesting, the stuff I was reading was saying it was more strict, thanks for the clarification.

@Shadow, utf8mb4 was introduced in MySQL 5.5.3, 2010-03-24.

@BillKarwin the OP wrote mysql 5, no information on the exact version.
